# Как правильно вставить дату?

Tags: python, selenium

помогите пожалуйста вставить дату,сначало выбираешь год,потом месяц,потом дату,заранее благодарен.

```
 <tr id="pn_tr" height="30" class="hid_tr">
                    <td valign="middle" class="styleBlack" width="34%" style="padding-left:10px;">
                        Passport Expiry Date: <span style="color:#F00">*</span>
                    </td>

                    <td width="66%" align="left" valign="middle">
                       <input type="text" name="pptExpiryDate" class="form-control-input" id="pptExpiryDate" value="" readonly="">
                    </td>
 </tr>
```

Пытался так:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"pptIssueDate"))).send_keys('2023-06-13')
```

[image: дата]

[image: месяц][image: день][image: год месяц день]

Answer (score 0):

Укажите id своего input и поменяйте дату.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('pptIssueDate').setAttribute('value', '2020-10-10')"
)
```